# Is there a calculator which supports arbitrary precision?

Tags: software-recommendation, calculator

I have got the standard `gnome-calculator` installed, but as I am dealing with rather large numbers at the moment, I need something more powerful which can actually deal with them without falling over. So for instance at the moment I need to convert [this large binary value to decimal](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/11351458/), but when using the standard Ubuntu calculator, I find that it is unable to even represent such a large number and simply falls over. I also found a number of online conversion tools which claimed to be able to deal with large numbers, but simply ended up crashing my browser and draining my CPU cores, and not actually giving me an answer, just an error message.

So really my question is, how can I convert and deal with such large numbers in Ubuntu without the tools simply falling over and not being able to deal with it? Can any body recommend me a tool which would be able to deal with such large numbers? Even by splitting the problem up by say calculating small numbers which make up the bigger one and then adding them together or something?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Comment: If you want arbitrary precision, the command line `bc` supports it, and apparently so does [KCalc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KCalc).

Comment: @muru: For what I am doing I need exact precision. Otherwise things will corrupt.

Comment: Arbitrary precision is what it's called. Aside from programs, various languages support it to (Python's integer is arbitrary precision by default, IIRC).

Comment: @muru: Oh, right, ok, sorry, I just read the wiki thing, and it didn't look like that, but maybe I misunderstood! :)

Comment: The very first line: "... or sometimes **infinite-precision arithmetic**". Seriously, Panda, read a little, please!

Comment: @muru: It was because it said that it would be limited by the system's memory, so that suggest that it would not necessarily be exact, but as exact as it could be on that system.

Comment: Well, if your number can't be held in memory at all, do you expect it to be computed on? Real world.

Comment: @muru: Hmm... Well, I guess not! :D

Comment: @muru: Could you perhaps convert that into an answer and explain how to do that in `bc`, and also in KCalc? :)

Comment: I don't have access to a GUI right now, so KCalc will have to wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion between bases in `bc` is fairly easy. Just set `ibase` and `obase` to the required bases. The default for both is 10, so we can just set `ibase` to 2. I used a file (named, say, `foo`) containing:

```
ibase=2
001000110010000100101111011000100110100100101111011100110110100000001010000010100100011001000110010001100100011001000100100011001000110010001100100011001000100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110010001100100011001000110000101000100011000010100010001100100000010100100110111101101111011101000110100101110100001000000100100001110101011101000110010101110010001000000110100101110011011101000110000101101100011011000111001000001010001000110010000000101101001011010010110100101101001011010010110100101101001011010010110100101101001011010010110100101101001011010010110100101101001011010010110100101101001011010010110100001010001000110000101000100011001000000110111101110000011110010111001001101001011010000111010000100000010011010110100101101000011000010110010101101100001000000110111101100101011011000110010101101110001010000010000001101101011010010110001101100001011001010110110000100000010000010010000001110010011011110110111101110100011010010111010000100000010001000100111100100000011011100110110000100000001010010010001100100000010100110110010101100101
```

Then did:

```
BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc < foo
```

And got:

```
540928155721638924086918713208358788434417421543582007398025141935037001065597779126307030345416152932763078192242002165296106229954746802320567748583763347185478212853751143760813806416888615744551880482630354587304366607401972680065884262510541490557699155628964583159402554268576902882264135962556243262400836720973400124956401049882543283755065968815271497932646828988752833868312831766775697322203661623283608105888116354992561077142244253199952119271560535664760689367070733955259652518580465356203287927104249900193248167970918611574830802565150864679884207701758286782698161317167183746874649374851424212625647735183268282102125722330298233134909640525556015561438701399837522556388933513135621744584178071469708112531395550265265874685017360628813885698355947673102075800592868146846498314366892439194433173009049785218842057219357555710703816876539540549373981950747068475487221385807538982981583758892582356159113797930824348243798067541314916691107657807727899269973612335790994508849402310357135063109363841802013850832833039341705117267300274974922172770739382935897246988186267375540666684309854217274165490358501220880594716147545409403437720568974932997534709589603856843924303666885450827859350799040200910334048954579348331089528105682738149303949572854468875687500880743898081167780496295200930920175473418789027999532104469254458591975148606912833663351309957251471935074750449462341683385434292854364223610892159790159597322715126394106554227171902975003734341684086839488627244161698998581023615716493188409171943277063107364544854644279824726209379471088806124844001225938604570562697680875076958389506783270442517437432056546267492402542750993809301236180450097406515720434936359867191790399745629069519764430331382284953699799681818716349571258784314300847178691858577907754955256555793349022793674314074605859075290896387489284851969597464902861397758662116931298733216874541511884865576132243589880093343144378853809953361771767531607603590045992477100597774201224130770167936473248164984312843522815331618527040539126714837245567046097395218547264596366848976384428510845471081772137481861904548761596193031547597366678724319337214428125621342181296829780853232081402476469948717356376515496139470348621547328931118203970915759446558628378862980758252816844512376308349164642713865128528685756813378861406016509958747160134201752088019982040676813529600987386905895971673763702043560323305802125556893287508358583841725843386699424384456022713792226657900326588728837071086202357787679856943219638527273481408963479024703769435105095103022310652877082969764409903965639292995374253547546225494024174003232684695335605310609305338530434193830115173158857319912924070883041848232544594384702484124121387971388555071652706246715269478748389093993092328175682959127655793124287989860862397767491884936603037279256937285190787226346484214801360991734359192308747285053107141358864051354038780994295686012721089301326976755524556391343138326542060276457012297941401590232862910769104159741097975047152186021090968906542583574255226369152539956016137431812056928383640519664246117338426572254573022098473718235982290375387763365068651085070884582217749629340891317532282698237897695333871760553691925080971473453446444173009767133222878699558193321924309898044650229107541430795328060040958350269496751010405772628119169416691856358380481166054707542620583827639208685757289227446931805961677574953701968330513472365877481402808418056640560591510690781915664120578413558628704361448157650082521966985910009636412441828936970071171700413199716910498168795035438639587102480391329778429405302152403569209621981666739205282867344400465325413380784985668775480552394745133545957728358681708922673716566071550874972201236514975119358854487473232986673293914400076206135184449335917858195555316655103883352798222617060489935762362647565362073134670087965234241567807408646946392171309077703775756026298096827042739559760381613017075325917984739125184959285533488365042734430045245135428221841905876134403293822728253180842801464270059758038483810244021192789295115050646048496330143117965517780443812212846827591005498768293165569320701166335471369330480656010222298241629210663796293707240628098364116400985499447497339801250607357131375089292084390727375422335011492901050151677098631868238872875708462285814083199731941467222294420539780585594528544414609487820070333151669011338030449359165281183735079502024127886293352814030599016021212072074309392582874770366891656863221312585204996521857418206685193346175930475378475968645793703186252466380619277436499675179857433767817666140959640973671615514177869108096268518803174520763094749446801027106024151461466773704927657566618857566150026412761351233356911827590746091798029653283180614459951837699383341502824632380516586857666029978789170124983191777405118710374911782243653303118050678058491637477689875742464689375996471925856990676935650352628713384003367136893837678485434186300674459149498604159948664285776255087988843038224697468755684194041167309670862590365355358538879210904696134673090873196613244349765654824347716580969940302272241496978815370303085735318048456833061087131425397867550603263613770229891529731666663380780533705858617958241210979792271369353787593124905202347646563990851145602089798406715373511987386693506177665067820004734125340300324573380011856712505177532679794021502770775863448607637502612616347799547160077238605563969136580720721417969258998038045512111568511105429440629901482504208766354943077060295234460003972481285613842020612468391230659424162484705700123096618621799186190870339493161625491065272999701279677789563808294981697908245624435560867506791513068097820127946446730013568685796818504041340369949206017476035685854512808573515740281148313308729014311516235442545341164203292003031921605990156473131409799499661407714985806721932917213192551553952152459346504506451529514440371692010104433101718764904914481886460147229544344835043694256757817453732564691515486695328935458184205712103792672714394496796650175835645022061426016983285490799170735701101570674879676900022618358793486052999737396902764908015595223920127839952972435072734531698217120089091337994042573818297968641469836661600344800046656614482781799500881362496916791152277508884356321487581788842876114282776715572788491391231956550259088983323753462806399618366214335151035919149408581389098172223870721570684284752032298966422351960017010728200727779542352839022071435973288503176957688321352762735738482925571430616715167096911730073647363490143137844194417307092239265712870422822411115152870559310896098445146658843423997617047284459218335095740603022207905283312265804516453339044752104700287823850086032839783934683811646502689576057460802180080344789600445673324592530747839048361780934649557506831743603227062988148740346426845900972754129378615756010464797318009828751805640667051121474003539885283201401369682015381475788440936618097688896413670937116592455158090247796179957537715118520351952621024296340947893606101015358540570267763775445786413425466994945303628446897863008029918632939671447679989806444891593536350232125308016047033857209153597517665210467447385123801771233640926347913500085207216361923985376062277878595064587971429980804728514697330912402861545942943296200421236595422521805156662610449052440306651031351230716119854145437957549140168011203973019873026341277528158755218554105658768548377327140499936958470235569671052619278855636752241412784819719907762477883370185553290106109177862549919412087363446890524079588023220342030703702822883661893114215495327054605921416792846453245700590042724612623352148419265348660662890170455190338924196577157671027367914042405460976327750627171938842973873762143512802767564323115727749016840131186211213049045123798266835064629736864502250280189490861268012215367707232042210380972321987338871904211209852670347995505217410236540445240256512875537765088477119029586101265881101911060981481916703599639888433805966074572308843778977614943319524721060013859088616517700249904069414768834019733019412393931059388831657407792528997010120846203502620112108499222549738139375258940272429577570091213300903392143910025376088631257455737784821942852855232781386998960015764850642193327542354929843841056404199099324061022032305170057946356973680591655536188613333394100082740004283436959382536803254050179188823612063179222471999091841763094604016740161387192704042069356630112157299291201187572089254082985249460110732358587899530517066670753260942405321764977858204941601813478275759633023749613619528806605210147594999616361385104883130286931221319770667661411383635153095095328427755823854537457098884913696981246690214280655576140860961347913535853782675109648393091276460155151940730068055819381457371565973052770871758675338579344453596931156750322061093640792866983330893492664632172525078856056128429458953567760307571471496114722393209216179834251554431388828086464780032992017700885757564859927752926055546760734059413401071577508577059834141130834171978392369297946574237445727446937379445843571310301061685621062563642223500993297652963634117959991873862047016866080985429873396279491071511749397786576056532774982020801134146070015744446931309442781358150133670709798953960214976371369337907849886197736890613766708017821491875617172904030141783585491550832093215355417101808480253995458795282848035373512341150109254886467997371897388975854059732723130643350275615111084323790136761704198666869744672485251686949366652468929048062934000286171292405461332936484617686999519304943986779468042040501836246919963938356159129351566308294853314582024491016657818032576779706311935123643239650076733970786309595873916172749316277364111533238239796803423940885081948639533947760772042112313907679289126951977984908092235055555521107008476340237124284039130577154129588625191991653692630751529598374455274411148052758257619390581662231071231373699077352045428469054072995950764518170763792651607814034908189567126690125591961378075754282425559168326674625188961682104587143131657411955593953534372714763768488582297643460582139414612311695142395743276894991992630284797170008373692712435607327441368911428268561979626891414258914935122829843528618332225544431228605439056702251191381944518590545580060419837320108392532217558958944048200551614511937201978649448927213852242395189177012618134929843640644313622960208620688151954087429590194322089420241169022569806159090436967581255791297642517202389040136428663821952509011718427610822950253968408790624257221769835503640351911867401505355165062373519721115242070441209058992484413517176793449346820097258010856899271838026977657975264203094354646549601999077537060749018056056823995233052227695434007319131848235936099162391471483031083926854641255658621032573829733619526531073302357237048803558127421789545488948547848140886288895907789022346675393439390856306403232677519883725742229841913983674439242264008036248063955598579616404522908461476276449723008468497990828174692077779175470626338106078699372903453291939483390099762747869316661225989897146878329752776511643047773850353012673151196343278489877123537151429752313361055568281253713678707032200926957301797609306263775972604402462953618013455103650249693610710395410627581902711455069113614751558230799571176887562400302063187310417347941993037648566059224734820807612734180251067484275074735215109365510574894987255253712154929509575717050193050472848569724724704743814269454430272299723260531007801114253370229792342272700367972181526890264620259154533832899579279484499054874453007899503151934532520052761574687436729779562891705012866874821819868357530350261631074436079698312149517000098815700718232211825375651163552984591967154156513509965874034537982640811988461505191482873836221267875924765980151179903671828081927452728591169081948577523231171572358964859970569671731510078307294413181653568177756825365532638713308111229691961624693434368067512408777135997258855523991492149858879546645314888312616631681106161010002988793755840253319857656854428083692228149176032302262104457603631107617794257516970386991333324292407411010073164007765212501309748866077668737706064457080182267278524137936154121658533616231081255216810016122556969363225803335924010302774288707849824076235267601102448767002397291556245565258524834446683239872079396562351825127878287945026823700750413184675394168348728583423189388791205514861416524960799640543671183450424545077447162493937532721248980386972313041850846467287291960038158013823180428835104239148187044110405641329357182583486368844942589189613664337216358484940887814533852876159310619692926111365976523688740222371832587546814194606178962035473672157389507498977010656497012949437430672536921534980033065211948113132338151560030934896742286315559600283018369600460251746351561119925454162645782321143197282845683028006612076058630530214517247766556456817153366030871776098281612896849472449948171070687845339758817773093790689556828398366722898077096031401629667867032863399485896792578133386645837031543045755815515580503201389902562117877575846064502486577525351055949646979887349002820560444599384996825292465215635278738321148684925085232183226916278107776820210327050731178736781295892768099726520121523603109974372628472341457887499070835986918397395502884842404526958051419317764794261900954402773755277206590589185953636398411181860831432380259168261743671888432920189040181224607625670039364995857444178758815382066912438970528452505440975201372413498775773782176804396850065412380869065677152806639452087953325308454682602206114642542120258157510428605879832535509284084474102263457932609993117367552986809015690936203177221701970094445184971888587902105669483112322732409467615667690067771063728916643895072559994285717481157380306307600776398338562686761470565655378819287241561148554173000906470193535228186209598013107198706827323779658694508976985962406923617005624476319430845995417914780315547754925408658494800221136863079143730390990929584554305396526809133883869644836052896415918345389740953864900669143125967013355966700682552161482958991179393388892800296361842992841221771157769706154450998833992709648156095856994425970896423806311679209916801860486640506432201331997891282953572043363567751218801027625635387866609966030486451128495541053378697263850625439147907169909829595137751437765033546710620247767693742614420112024871191570336480342537148735535681343749293028143949078404214797841705910094543333644063645792217806839243258009646575015798305865046275719646227878469777128193835748009603693517573933091023250065061744161957449230256240713800261253704279349368009487513404719814786674795512100813098475499273104722438621217200032166323317675397742086342314466770489266882410038477667752137871680188578278716807357575139636550694782421335141448191762670047203751262472611930267048692832490248946717050460085290420033782281149340028779533275478988107645665114982255154114489959666468259125249201443799802142390853018131204142564245473263267483258280726948623460960080668234354074658290745389482166010709579610234937842259913155287995445459072597642497677523107870929965705194957066077430040399745512987356683680042054038978469343468268764348008083357760968184834394509415801574743789097085670242408134791935778770748665378064531430467190249869660937905072588004187011935081267182929408720216903422301268950798802361275663226155950075841308799189661255918412580938654276348414872992849263887110410973951870157483632601749384623081741513831192257089893038531044463939777446142597173193265486420029999899590444376075636194610352568048498283809526006099073314084222969889724841047531612958816828496471995200469872764738975417786191273541911796532319219600958861072907430877124479890038292856247905723170037466900773854035818278190263783074733611901499896850606971537740748369110356993407585517589627120892069419861486466038632096710612210997435184455669638185753440879834519872894786904180944800089301978539220965275754733980705032596578252781765477524620968207382026896224214508606553583001560940996944139633818228803374927091538068938745345229431765536918430615288163933595457230376875784004814691471045480892842201690711657271345322698174412987419256739485686180770251680198817390086637865199644753617225925592454949521061940777849371060416437898697894723297570424834982441358711584655456426772512928146485256234414580131155795790777460073406997501582986155871560181454533755667234817044066607969499100543440479666955945883970038990694287975612903983713216836178284368879953027184987923780508377181753099635059356971762531455282307415359201094625141168803797341022004858276568847136649745817756768912152446869145603964699482589604372218850615406041066092802479863835424258099315868354361227530900317035892121224430625017746443353140300768403831589448292751557583302524279003457804075259713387627130955829651001414094162479793195228133308433875833550064016993004860466901396555858499010294862449594940609489725584889464677819382699674835260488987320712326901786050266256829215241640434621879104988243685036690287131927208652477100669410872875572690352511679675944839720004596896769172051236903547886545497649787314020891697029091604513962615591258302791176506623804252326951993697967063349727680289766565366580729511038520211849084867479679858132563837329643769600415880142106597309169408518676401611772188566765179822425978940904017028012187195829317661463899533884179018543011512181435707222687621029933010712896497597066445418414555945759794147396911013171512393141173844251689557921404703042329282218502815785537655816325326442629402458657740526801548500173792715002248351350462516303887840570465538674191539208178696813816533317072692517512888975121507841680123563576289456171974781423489219704719570933160681299910727891594202488353277077630411106881607107502254730194439739845760221652199852252019220986871867271833650587117499750967631515135398762980139977677135373585421811087661697467109989400371645208614481580021103120949008432049065004827227733437921601801358705608998606880788971961915331469395992539461729235823426174798963632429069172524835912771425623396553145077982840705413497143128727419449217785492674011656459044483151721619126132623009232532289842745730601070278029834070536803821329487391266384597296104120299249488628433662268981134338244172181725241394555450625821585175304574427378660322724528972105242082321144737715150299734258479143279865758360592146738603700056339960631713256945955563864324093311702318109258622548835888760083402659385665998007939242062910718937439047760230297849910237285133725908608334982308577575917848522009763397395069022760817844920006117642124800375518670935201310096494604603712076580259409523298474965738454909880206274770356114920840872323427931213808846343025019219933956425886856297832607288718082312429931227175702363752977653629508044693983165149909524554280699983204657821208639790420469238732451027426461327866616281454389705578612970015539794295074169437682764076639064275656268049680410261297951418798660769957899851159404553317547395744358832038046856933650953392638295115066977015237841148452505359377227119410675904926135276768783162733636313697444296291390162512845259000471680020334289942981476457309543209992486509372530209907148578361639651828866923222531171473696367769629717415819920435969632819597385488886557206252530092067804316606760001346399803001401522915386755056133667575747236074305023808959945690623825137557137623413494500488419902198414147932114701494580789783149328799389088594437408743844318692101567293978229797852934309987153588030889074484116228882904080182875901062634317712919085152791576633554876859672105855481577090698226573908968765818766165412279324894142162336280263240753208535475755461630438906517427803852973995449157637400190296871722406738338402139842402313138020142720687075259861556382940281488181974286285685374151362895226434182131237221842295126257001533004860790820490935756067877746582749865439454792131201330464847660036897351206648516385950348187265817073176247897197255381656977256932756670059630367325578978820144735462154994169858643722519002999550720765940563649952561055802868341928451219947468470053658126668062372907128592309626122272794055037695086691098063490598952833046889135434738911171186305751612690722478661327333386192308980843504946637297764113529549157620070663912514382330403715407802911549376694586240909875562366201093852663242933206022216078082648003940283580514904847467516288638005126249076266620090258647388751616985010311655560496956209049607368183005755818965470770620464625807444457323579178297889262107819709193223223835906615163672423877062065736876544549554261729662536624339163715059786552224179485251903360963810527034771227729745591192743891310580250918661045158529074006309233078026815113706790211070605378119588480767803585263715431571151888280085231424038309570372818183785200060611762391872322787945943151435256330100606724496874929473426110405729639850266035319438191365931304354926441330578083838012937665921863696648199771148093528136157021897086395595965754415412835666093209793534795560644940815146905603638448772735145047722086831554739556964985107455587303392662123146962417829081673909735871748618151085711972671324566135271397021464722577442750977380827764661348517138293413109065684395308163493818664349386293684486085595121606540722396023950263360508658611668430553213531224677135684690914110710133906632929720266420245274291025295889091801201370377142529891106947298036217751507090824347904168868452840450915171577347626904891859903219889668186068714676413459230297291329202368344209538895901049946976605186119357173973278787746043739502650414186769612319748479925903132359498015464458419265600313168869483205987618394736325316244516307014010765024527781030449768577984555684357042853948385442080416689982002461891765493170507982817261409940552399875974405257206466028867912404927973765733792416936860136520676943231150528215622460966492219153292703811697590092847143160144719621036932153852388655466546146940447173619659401689453453568401809390306855619292676964550422578889204590278537763133841179272776767507196171196701995748927673061968853010561505257484565238169798034313493942742062634198248546349815345631347804060362465733585176228652771162666382059417747080990433748924647344939184328178631068937734534870437450906318007898887164669449097681676080302385416486898617320986424810959094419225755760391277824217763527838816378952779016455547873765386998142364608216420634434080864274481744683938857200312306998482152147811081897826936617184166022685327408271449891112560589067380249892154464111243384540020460397787906460489673561025721322264138123630687033131422216636375960068332982892950730754636582889522122293746331078590937626765494253439236306192486104339478707168798654606049143947785052348839292342370217654041022003571514997533659211273565615467580896938210676991319161743027450427540428183344077673192934029786298566548874247442786059617905299886537450209682696845617282342565358813391607862434288339524783657492451539149797213765478496996504398828575328313181376429102205075942651953309625848264914383334692335788813115002363420185894337365233781715534821337408217961125597926554706871588458935318228226949464330704041681831529903024520248040901380173102579509672956019276805715293947768287150323662677273648266405753380317899112252933340906202284886112391326030638866828090178880653735485311764847551615080185283434954728127925384535030694424914104563126180419107565748824740304950629972467315779357915542445132849016817905414782440795946914698188888647033572599742681820213457671771147257627098576247927306014481277688863725498958743399548727428672874482164432332914819035005961487757632290098035375547049961109127814522419819446619091283333369479110961923374454148665661069177949830685980871176531808187110463163543269099931320495345574623489501162067456352763103373949233510618156808799897404597047545905620882899828221727548733491512701791086830330757223289382812352747552035807091414786353351374150877363834594606575671153775027377950852792212627960203974471012397285475263019181669322595640337377066662919108411156257024126095246255442218126144916942791776967942548141168064606390737782795198120247358025233608174732702795373998734718022776525009353875853184362105650253157866604117648140264617162356504691441302513477297054812085254030749905430702593434997777026660046294160264820738100485451287917145491978894271248161390265370521946232280786732837169732758718793984692983845313796974046817514500582657811198391781158073267155247516862108370701260525478014425582059625462694971886982161120579556682292458327552074316491753809925791587262247992984470735032633665188635258544000477856076702708986358498262622063433507734552775913221877154578289583956765747555309388022023799330022966882861896818128154375907197275462648514106610004805520875706032859294412477471184960330717934571342284888409008338728943597554798486129397742138855034996516289619795102097202061962446606263816248115852284112682975035724280724953583629478911063346627341129899604740895494395312106562702326864321040008947643678126969000315550638059160674527014412661109211024568446632522207439374887514007165840904989819162680451127163622025806417687374148525621943397567653255512081930090178241737251650465048996591314187082260059330988618814391540346860840031723832772627712010916093783024227870912892877556070884940825376513465477851647328966422242624834403728210267327653635629053843109133786103543136490303345862462855672052760467762906333062375230588255089459215488310658230529704067552945569043420104610583671920065461681756181446316082442103647870094026489666523730042788978339087622450667927923289756447429024498030508181566293409881990798916112182785285205455181846865648970202211464848369906675902712387042238245603904448608138863170928627175643025754140514092765450815837974256612301204292317774142754481194035643011553418467681574039147190996826512044412924500346586188859012968037914647302073388431253365051137933668394615774480290604107467665272745861019169999287047562099867126792705149615172760949138702578193505684167742379373789061938484398226922108325347476082942270850391102444578650896653301035025348106029413430792954928531968707896615029235938479706301787493867260782548189743282308399573645223830651492189491866927892060043846411723801675950392806463787560076482163349876517074971874173878852438850156830644435531001045082456985955878156768528750618780131129180319528568738657886044239802882515276353619431071118474070648192832219987748872659780695975238634339962023430198657892131106503429198111318235817939384851562431578698123676556762921783362348806575569223735388251668740604257924078030004427991945819640114794576912520008745947203649357785695753442668736323658788573027481777311068477557820489316707332266677176784759682805725590069600110697164749797364997686479164620036144539749500853748984608297095222450214499361207388345321032656766020726057031448447309844028604331535881064008651930193406505179841945946681533779002355924459474150646151285303272996333561046245491557029420384489977854999648026592906625194573074374313405392605175780026240559487806222028399879399737768605324956420161253204826888513589859374608986547885250194235678666371578003226833199339010496755634683583065070719399249295227282109548744
```

`bc` prints output split into multiple lines if it exceeds the length, so if you have a very long number, set `BC_LINE_LENGTH` to 0 to make it print in one line.

Comment: So is `ibase` the base which I am inputting, and `obase`, they base that is being outputted?

Comment: Yep, input base and output base, respectively. "ibase and  obase  define  the  conversion
       base  for  input  and  output  numbers.  "

Comment: When I execute the command I just get: `(standard_in) 1: illegal character: _
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: L
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: I
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: N
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: _
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: L
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: N
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: G
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: T
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: H`.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda where did you put `BC_LINE_LENGTH=0`, I wonder.

Comment: I created the file in my home directory, then went to Terminal and executed the command (after executing `bc`). Is that not where I am meant execute the command?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda No, it's meant to be executed in the shell directly. The file is input to `bc`. O.o Why would you run `bc` within `bc`?

Comment: Oh dear... Ooops!

Comment: I see that it only goes up to base 16, is there any way to make it go any higher?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda nope. The legal values are "The legal values
       of ibase are 2 through 16.". You'll probably have to use something like Python, or a full-fledged tool like Sage or Matlab for that.

Comment: And how would I install `Sage` or `Matlab`? Also, what are the minimum and maximum values for doing such an operation in KCalc?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda KCalc is like GNOME Calculator, a GUI with fixed options (2, 8, 10, 16). MATLAB is a commercial product, unless you have plenty of money you might be better of using [GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), an open source competitor (available in the repositories). Sage can be installed using their PPA: https://launchpad.net/~aims/+archive/ubuntu/sagemath. It all depends on what you're actually doing here.

Comment: There is another rather large number which I want to convert into decimal and is currently in binary format. I have tried using the method you give through `bc`, but it's just giving me a shorter output still in binary. Why is this? What am I doing wrong? It is so large in fact that my clipboard doesn't like it so I can't easily show it to you! But it fills up a txt file to 7.3MB! :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24142/discussion-between-muru-and-paranoid-panda).

Comment: Could you please have a look at the chat that this discussion was moved to, as I have another question for you on the same subject, also I'm wondering if you computer has finished calculating that large number I am in need of.